# Hadoop Map Task : Read the content of a specified input file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera, hadoop-partitioning

I'm pretty new to Hadoop environment. Recently, I run a basic mapreduce program. It was easy to run.

Now, I've a input file with following contents inside input path directory

```
fileName1
fileName2
fileName3
...
```

I need to read the lines of this file one by one and create a new File with those names (i.e fileName1, fileName2, and so on) at specified output directory.

I wrote the below map implementation, but it didn't work out

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
                throws IOException {

            String fileName = value.toString();
            String path = outputFilePath + File.separator + fileName;
            File newFile = new File(path);

            newFile.mkdirs();
            newFile.createNewFile();
        }
```

Can somebody explain me what I've missed out ?

Thanks

Comment: Please do read the basics of MR/Hadoop and do some practice and post a query.

Comment: @PraveenSripati  : Please let me know what needs to be done here..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get started with studying the **FileSystem** class, I think you can only create files in the distributed filesystem. Here's a code example of where I opened a file for reading, you probably just need a FSDataOutputStream. In your mapper you can get your configuration out of the Context class.

```
    Configuration conf = job.getConfiguration();
    Path inFile = new Path(file);
    try {
        FileSystem fs;
        fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

        if (!fs.exists(inFile))
            System.out.println("Unable to open settings file: "+file);

        FSDataInputStream in = fs.open(inFile);
                    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all get the path of the input directory inside your mapper with the help of **FileSplit**. Then append it to the name of the file which contains all these lines and read the lines of this file using **FSDataInputStream**. Something like this :

```
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context)
                    throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit)context.getInputSplit();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(context.getConfiguration());
        FSDataInputStream in = fs.open(new Path(fileSplit.getPath().getParent() + "/file.txt"));
        while(in.available() > 0){
                    FSDataOutputStream out = fs.create(new Path(in.readLine()));
        }
       //Proceed further....
}
```

Comment: FSDataInputStream is deprecated.
you must use BufferedReader. (see more information in DataInputStream)